# Query database and check not equal to

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I have a data set in excel that I am querying info in a database using that data set. However, when checking against the database I get the "too few parameters. Expected 1" error.

Query:

```
Set rex = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [CallQuality] WHERE ([Racf] = '" & sRacf & "') AND ([DateChecked] = #" & sDateChecked & "#) AND ([Overall] <> '" & sOverall & "') ;")
```

Literal:

```
SELECT * FROM [CallQuality] WHERE ([Racf] = 'SMITHJ') AND ([DateChecked] = #2017/05/17#) AND ([Overall] <> 'Development Required') ;
```

I have tried without the brackets and using `!=` instead of `<>`. I am sure it is something simple I am missing.

Edit:
Error in this section:

```
Set rex = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [CallQuality] WHERE ([Overall] <> '" & sOverall & "')")
```

Edit2:
The field name was wrong. Sorry guys! Not sure why it didnt give me the name error when it didnt find the field. 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does it return anything if you just run `SELECT * FROM [CallQuality]` Also can you post more code?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. Yes, it returns everything from the table, as expected. The rest of the code relates to a loop to go through the entire dataset - we dont get to loop due to the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with the field name in the query.

Answer (score 0):

use a `+` instead of `&` in the query.

So use this:

```
Set rex = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [CallQuality] WHERE ([Racf] = '" + sRacf + "') AND ([DateChecked] = #" + sDateChecked + "#) AND ([Overall] <> '" + sOverall + "') ;");
```

If you look in the Error List you should get:

> Error CS0019  Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'string' and 'string'

I can see why you put the `&` instead. Simple mistake :-)

Comment: Or even better, use parameterized queries!

Comment: Touché - Yes, that would be better.

Comment: I have always used `&` to join  strings and it hasnt been an issue before. Also, while testing this the error only came in when adding the last element "overall". Even on its own it doesnt work so the issue appears to be with that lest element of the query.

Comment: what about using `not in`  instead of `<>`

also try moving the query about, is it not the `#` ?

Comment: Havent used that before so referred to support. Tried a few variations like `"SELECT * FROM [CallQuality] WHERE ([Overall] Not In '" & sOverall & "')"` but errored out. "In operator without () in query expression". Its not the   `#`, I am now working on just the last part of the query (ill update the question) which doesnt include the `#`

Comment: Um, no. In VBA, `&` *is* the string concatenation operator.

Comment: @Andre I realised it was VBA after 10 mins of me posting that, I was doing mine in c# !!!